# Loop using array with predifned sheets - VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am new to the site and new to vba coding and very new to loops, currently i am trying to summarize the data in a workbook which has total 25 sheets and these sheets are not fixed based on the issues we have the list of sheets maximum of 25 (2 (View Recon & Open Items) are main sheets on which my codes are run and add new sheets upto additional 23 sheets). I want to summarize the data of 10 sheets which were generated using view recon in Summary tab from ROW 4. For example sheet names (sheet2, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12, 14, 17, 18, 19), here sheet names are fixed and number of sheets are not fixed it can be 1-10.

I tried using - this is not working for me as i might have defined incorrectly

```
Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In Sheets(Array("Sheet2", "Sheet5", "Sheet7", "Sheet9", "Sheet10", "Sheet12", "Sheet14", "Sheet17", "Sheet18", "Sheet19"))
```

Then my code to summarize it - which is working fine when i do it separately but i am not able to define and use with array, would be helpful if any of you can help me to get it corrected.

Happy weekend!

Thanks for your help!

Regards
Suresh

Answer (score 1):

Use the Worksheet [.Names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx) as strings in a variant array. As you progress through each in turn, define your worksheet in a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx).

```
Dim w As Long, vWSs As Variant

vWSs = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet5", "Sheet7", "Sheet9", "Sheet10", "Sheet12", "Sheet14", "Sheet17", "Sheet18", "Sheet19")

For w = LBound(vWSs) To UBound(vWSs)
    With Worksheets(vWSs(w))
        'here you will use .Range("A1") or .Cells(r, c)
        'the prefix period means the parent worksheet is
        'the one currently defined by the With ... End With
    End With
Next w
```

That is my own preferred method. As far as your own `For Each sh In ...` the same  could be used like this.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In Sheets(Array("Sheet2", "Sheet5", "Sheet7", "Sheet9", "Sheet10", "Sheet12", "Sheet14", "Sheet17", "Sheet18", "Sheet19"))
    With sh
         'Use .Range or .Cells here
    End With
Next sh
```

Comment: Thanks Expert but i am not able to get the code corrected, would be helpful if you can see this, but i am not able to post it fully will try to use asnwer and post it

Comment: What are the name(s) of the worksheets in the name tabs at the bottom of the worksheet window?

Comment: @Jeeped: your second code example is exactly the same as OP's code, namely looping over an array of strings. Where's the improvement? The fault must be with something else, or do I miss the obvious?

Comment: @user1016274 - The code in the question will work as long as the **sh** variable is properly referenced. I was offering a way to refer to the worksheet within each iteration of the loop without repeatedly **sh** variable. With no working code that referred to an actual worksheet, the OP could have been using `Range("A1")` and expecting that to reference the correct parent worksheet.